# Generic type requires 1 type argument(s), but only when broken out to a separate type

Tags: typescript, typescript-typings, typescript-generics

I have a simple setup that looks something like this is and is completely happy:

```
export interface CustomState {
  someBool: boolean;
  status: string;
}

function statePropDifferent<K extends keyof CustomState>(props: { stateKey: K, value: CustomState[K] }) {
  return this.state[props.stateKey] !== props.value;
}
```

I wanted to extract this to its own type so I could reuse it in a different function, but it throws and error in the IDE `Generic type 'CustomState' requires 1 type argument(s)`. Why doesn't it do this when declared inline and how can I fix it?

```
type StateCompareProps<K extends keyof CustomState> = { stateKey: K, value: CustomState[K] };

function statePropDifferent(props: StateCompareProps) {
  return this.state[props.stateKey] !== props.value;
}
```

EDIT: fixed copy/pasta mistake

Comment: You have to pass the K to `StateCompareProps`, just by doing `props: StateCompareProps<K>`

Comment: does this code gives you error: https://tsplay.dev/w65qvW

Answer (score 0):

Since your generic type is not optional, yo do need to send the generic type when using StateCompareProps as `StateCompareProps<'status'>` for example. So for that you'd need to make statePropsDifferent function as a generic function again. and this again requires you to send the type when calling like `statePropDifferent<'status'>({stateKey: status, value: 'pending'})`

Only way I know of solving this is like below:

```
export interface IProps {
  someBool: boolean;
  status: string;
}

export interface IState extends IProps {
...
// extra state property if needed
}

function statePropDifferent(props: Partial<IProps>) {
  const state: IState = this;
  (Object.keys(props) as (keyof IProps)[]).some(
    (key) => state[key] !== props[key]
  );
}
```

This might not be what you want. But this is what I did in similar situation.